# MSWord 2016 returning multiple words with <*> wildcard search

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

I am working in an API reference document, and I need to edit a large number of lines in 1 shot. The lines all look like `int/void/string App*` and I need to edit them all to say "int App*". I wrote a simple wildcard find search that looks like `<[!i]*> <App*>` and it selects any number of words between the first < >.

Every MSWord resource I've read suggests that using < > tells Word to explicitly select one word only. From [Microsoft themselves](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/find-and-replace-text-and-other-data-in-a-word-document-c6728c16-469e-43cd-afe4-7708c6c779b7):

> The less than and greater than symbols (< >) mark the start and end of each word, respectively. ***They ensure that the search returns a single word.***

[Relevant Screenshot of incorrect matching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljbq1.png)
[Lines that I'm trying to match](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlfGn.png)

Is there something I'm doing wrong here or is this some sort of bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your correct expression is this:

- Find:
  `\<[^>]@\> \<([^>]@)\>`
- Replace to:
  `int \1`

> Every MSWord resource I've read suggests that using < > tells Word to explicitly select one word only.

`> and`< indeed match word boundaries, however it matches only one word only in case the expression inbetween is also correct, however you don't need to use them in your expression.

You need to escape them (`\<`) to match them literally.

Other changes in your expression:

- `[^>]` - you need to match text not containing the closing `>`
- `*` to `@` - in Word regular expressions `*` maintains its general "zero or more characters" role, you need to use `@` for "previous once or more"

Comment: I'm sorry, I may have confused you with the <> symbols and I just realized the relevant lines of what I'm trying to match are just underneath the screenshot. The lines I'm trying to match look like "int App" or "string App" or "void App", etc. So I'm trying to use the <> to match just ONE word before the "App", as I understand is what it's supposed to do.

Comment: if you want to match just one word before App, then use e.g. `<[A-Za-z]@> App`

Comment: Ah, I see now. It was the * that was throwing me off. Thank you. The final search query ended up looking like `<[!i][a-zA-Z:]@> (<App*>)`, because I didn't want to match lines that already said 'int' and some lines had colons as well.

Comment: Even that probably should have been `<[!i][a-zA-Z:]@> (<App[a-zA-Z]@>)`, but it did work